# Child window does not stay on top after file selection

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, window

I've constructed a user interface (UI) using Python's (2.7) Tkinter. The UI has buttons that allow the user to access a second window. On this child window, the user clicks a button that allows them to search for a file of a specific filetype.

Problem: However, after the user selects the file, the child window falls behind the main window. How can I force the child window to stay on top, at least until the user is done w/ the form?